# Why can't I use 'the shadow' of something

Tags: articles, nouns

I'm creating some application UI. Say when the user clicks a button, a shadow will be created for the given object in the page. And a message will appear saying: Do you want to keep `the shadow`?

I'm not a native English speaker so when someone suggested me to change the wording to `a shadow` I feel so hard to accept.
Is it correct that I need to change the wording like he said? And why can't I use `the` here?
What I have in mind is that `the` refers to some particular thing - the created shadow.

Comment: Basically, a duplicate of a question I already answered. The first mention is "a"; The second mention is "the". https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/156455/should-i-use-the-definite-article-or-indefinite-article-in-this-sentence/156456#156456 Do you want an apple? The apple is on the table. Like that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL stackexchange. Regardless of the correct answer, I think you should omit the article. Since you're designing an application UI, "keep shadow?" seems the most appropriate to me

Comment: If the shadow appears, and the question comes after it: Keep the shadow?

Comment: You already know what shadow is being referred to—it's visible on the screen. The use of **the** is appropriate. Further, the use of **a** in that context would not be. The suggestion to changing the wording was misguided. However, you could always hedge your bets and use **this** (which might actually be better anyway).

Comment: Hi @ColleenV, well, the native speaker who suggested me to use 'a' said that the shadow actually belongs to some other object, so that's why I'm wondering if there are any subtle differences with other nouns like 'car'/'cat'/'cup of tea'. If there isn't such a difference, I think I've made a duplicated question. Thanks